# Reference tables in FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a set of tables that are mapped through reference tables (Products, Stores and StoreProducts)

**Tables**

```
Table: Product
---------------
Name
Id
Desc


Table: Stores
---------------
Name
Id
ZipCode

Table: StoreProduct
---------------
Id
StoreId
ProductId
isAvailable
ShelfID
```

**Models**

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool isAvailable {get;set;}
    public int ShelfId {get;set}
    public List<Store> Stores {get;set;}
}
```

**Mappings**

```
public class StoreMap: ClassMap<Store>
{
    public StoreMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Length(255).Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Products)
            .Table("StoreProduct")
            .ParentKeyColumn("StoreId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ProductId");

    }
}

public class ProductMap: ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Length(255).Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Stores)
            .Table("StoreProduct")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ProductId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("StoreId");

    }
}
```

I've looked at [FluentNHibernate Lookup Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494055/fluentnhibernate-lookup-table) but cant see how to apply this to my structure.  Am I going down the right lines? How do I map the StoreProduct table to each of the Domain models with the Fluent Mapping?

Secondly, how do I map a column from the reference lookup table to the child table (see the isAvailable column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a many-to-many relationship here. A store contains many products, a product can be carried by more than one store.

something like this

```
public ProductMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name).Length(255).Nullable();
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Stores)
        .AsBag()
        .Table("StoreProduct")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out and update the question/accept the answer as appropriate.